# Download, Print option in PowerBI embedded report with Angular7

Tags: angular, typescript, azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I have created PowerBI report and It has been embedded to my angular7 client application by registering the application with Azure Active Directory(AAD). It embeds perfectly. I want to allow that embedded report to be downloaded, printed by the user of my client application. Following is my Angulr7 code to embed the PowerBI report.

```
      showReport() {
    // Report's Secured Token
    let accessToken = 'myAccessToken';
    // Embed URL
    let embedUrl = 'embedUrl';
    // Report ID
    let embedReportId = 'embedReportId';
    let config = {
      type: 'report',
      accessToken: accessToken,
      embedUrl: embedUrl,
      id: embedReportId,
      settings: {
        localeSettings: {
          language: "en",
          formatLocale: "es"
        }
      }
    };
    // Grab the reference to the div HTML element that will host the report.
    let reportContainer = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('reportContainer');
    // Embed the report and display it within the div container.
    let powerbi = new pbi.service.Service(pbi.factories.hpmFactory, pbi.factories.wpmpFactory, pbi.factories.routerFactory);
    let report = powerbi.embed(reportContainer, config);
    var rep = powerbi.get(reportContainer);
    // Report.off removes a given event handler if it exists.
    report.off("loaded");
    // Report.on will add an event handler which prints to Log window.
    report.on("loaded", function () {
      console.log("Loaded");
    });
  }
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can print the report by calling `report.print()`:

```
var element = document.getElementById('#myReport');
var report = powerbi.get(element);

report.print()
  .catch(error => { ... });
```

See [Print a report](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript/wiki/Embedding---Basic-interactions#print-a-report) in the official docs too. This will show the Print dialog, but the result isn't nice. Usually through printing you can create PDF file too, because there is no way to export a report as file (PDF, PowerPoint) using the API. [SaveAs](https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/demo/v2-demo/index.html#) will allow you to make a copy of the report in the service, not as a file on the local disk.

```
// Get a reference to the embedded report HTML element
var embedContainer = $('#embedContainer')[0];

// Get a reference to the embedded report.
report = powerbi.get(embedContainer);

var saveAsParameters = {
    name: "newReport"
};

// SaveAs report
report.saveAs(saveAsParameters);
```

Comment: report.print()
  .catch(error => { ... }); This line of code does not work with angular 7.

Comment: OK, just get rid of the catch part.

Comment: It raises this error after removing catch part. error TS2339: Property 'print' does not exist on type 'Embed'

Comment: Looks like you also removed the parentheses. It must become `report.print();`.

Comment: Nope. report.print(); is there.

Comment: Can you just tell me where this print method comes from? Is it coming from powerbi-client?

Comment: https://microsoft.github.io/PowerBI-JavaScript/classes/_src_report_.report.html#print

Comment: @AndreyNikolov report.print() is creating single page in pdf even thought report height is too much big. Is there any way I can print report as fit to width and take required number of pages in pdf?

Comment: @parth.hirpara Use [Export to file API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/export-to).

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented this below code in angular 6

// Import powerbi-client

```
import * as pbi from 'powerbi-client';
```

// Variable declaration

```
let reportPrint;
```

//Inside the print function

```
let reportContainer = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('reportContainer');
let powerbi = new 
pbi.service.Service(pbi.factories.hpmFactory,pbi.factories.wpmpFactory, 
pbi.factories.routerFactory);
this.reportPrint = powerbi.get(reportContainer);

this.reportPrint.print().catch(error => {  
    console.log(error);
});
```